# Why am I not getting the appropriate error messages displayed upon (network) request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to work out how to receive helpful error messages on the client side, but keep getting generic error messages. For example, trying to sign up with an email that is not available should result in the `email@email.com is already in use` error message. I, however, get the generic `Request failed with status code 409` message, which is obviously unhelpful to the user. The network response is as expected as seen in the screenshot below. What gives? Why am I not getting the same error message as my (Redux) payload?

Below are the relevant code snippets.

**Sign up controller**

```
export default {
  signup: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { fullname, username, email, password } = req.body;

      // Check if there is a user with the same email
      const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (foundUser) {
        return res.status(409).send({ error: `${email} is already in use` });
      }

      const newUser = await User.create({
        fullname,
        username,
        email,
        password,
      });

      // Assign token to succesfully registered user
      const token = authToken(newUser);

      return res.status(200).send({ token, user: newUser });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },
};
```

**Sign up action**

```
export const createAccount = ({
  fullname,
  username,
  email,
  password, 
  history
}) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.CREATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
  });

  try {
    const {
      data: {
        newUser: { token, user },
      },
    } = await request.post('/auth/signup', {
      fullname,
      username,
      email,
      password,
    });

    localStorage.setItem('auth-token', token);

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.CREATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS,
      payload: user
    });

    // Redirect to home
    history.push('/home');
  } catch (error) {    
    dispatch({ 
      type: actionTypes.CREATE_ACCOUNT_FAILURE, 
      payload: error.message
    });
  }
};
```

**Sign up network response**

[image]

**Redux sign up error payload**

[image]

Comment: did you try attaching only error not error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'error.response.data.error' instead of 'error.message'